# Why two-dimensional presentation of data called "table"?

Tags: etymology

I just wonder why a word "table" is also used as two-dimensional presentation of data?

It's just a single flat plate, I think "shelf" is more proper representation of such a concept.

Comment: Maybe because it is a *tabular* format? See [tabula rasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabula_rasa).

Comment: Just curious, what about a shelf makes it more suitable than a table?  It seems that a shelf and a table vary in how they are supported (and perhaps positioned in a room) and the analogy doesn’t seem to carry that far.

Comment: @Drew Yes. Perhaps the more apposite question might have been why the word *table* applied to something with four legs, used for eating from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table is usually either square or rectangular (which is why a "round table" is always clearly called "round table", but you never hear anyone talking of a "square table"). 
So it has four sides, parallel two by two, which allows for rows and columns.

As you said, this is for a two-dimensional presentation.
Your idea of a shelf is excellent...for a three dimensional presentation.

Answer (score 1):

As defined on [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/table), the word "table" comes from the Latin "tabula" which means

> board, tablet, list

In the case of a two-dimensional presentation of data, it was likely called a table because it's a list of figures.

Comment: And the word *table* as a four-legged piece of furniture is called that because it's the surface upon which you spread out such an ordered list. That is, the word for the piece of furniture is the derivative term, not the word for the list itself.

Comment: @AndrewLeach that's not what Josh's etymology link states.

Comment: @MartinSmith Except that the Latin word for the furniture is *mensa,* and *table* (as a piece of furniture) certainly does not derive from *mensa.*

Comment: @AndrewLeach I don't speak Latin but according to the link one of the meanings for tabula was "writing table" and the original meaning of the term itself was "small flat slab or piece"?

Answer (score 0):

***[Table](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=table):***

> - ***"arrangement of numbers or other figures on a tabular surface for convenience"*** is recorded from late 14c. (as in table of contents, mid-15c.).

(Etymonline)